# Delete a database entry from list of entries from a webpage

Tags: django, templates, radio-button

I am trying to get a user input from a web page having multiple radio buttons on it, and i need to delete the selected radio button data from the database of employees.

In my views I have,
views.py

```
def list(request):
  listofemp = Emp.objects.all()
  if request.method=='POST':
    selected_entry = Emp.objects.get(pk=request.POST['e'])
    selected_entry.delete()
  return render_to_response("listemp.html",locals(),context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

In my listemp.html i have this template.

```
<!doctype Html>
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
           <form method='POST' action='/deleted'>
            {% csrf_token %}
                <p>    
                {% for e in listofemp %}
                <li><a href= "{{e.pk}}">{{ e.name }} </a></li> {{ e.depart }}
                <input type='radio' name="e" id="e{{forloop.counter}}" value= "{{e.pk }}" />
                {% endfor %}

                </p>


                <input type='submit' value=''/>
            </form>
           <li><a = href='/alldetails'> List all the Details together <a/></li>    
        </body>




    </html>
```

I am getting a multiDict error at "e", and cannot understand how to delete the selcted entry from my database. Here is my models.py file.

```
from django.db import models

class Emp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    depart = models.CharField(max_length= 16, choices = (('FINANCE','FINANCE'),('MARKETING','MARKETING')))
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Can you post the exact traceback you are getting? And also put `print request.POST` as the first line of your `if` block and post the output?

Comment: I am getting a GET request back. I tried with GET, and its saying MutiDictError at e.

Comment: also, print (request.POST) gives <QueryDict: {}>
and print (request.POST) gives <QueryDict: {}>

Comment: Since you are getting a POST I think it is because you are posting to `/deleted` without a trailing slash, and Django is redirecting to `/deleted/`, and a redirect is always GET. Change the action URL.

Comment: Wow.Its quite interesting to know this. It will help me in future, but anyhow i redesigned my code, i was running low on time and i just needed it to work. I am using URL links instead of radio buttons now to delete. (I am very new to Django , 5 days old )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to the fact that you set the names of all the radios to be the same, i.e. the name "e". Try to assign different names for the multiple radios inside the for loop.

Comment: names are different. there is a forloopcounter for that. Names are e1 ,e2 ,e3,e4,e5,e5 etc ....

Comment: you made the id's different, not the names. it's the name that gets passed in the POST dictionary.

Comment: I mean the name for the input field.